# ¿Se puede validar campos de un formulario con el mismo nombre que contiene document.getElementById(id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola colegas tengo una duda y es ¿como puedo validar un formulario que me trae dos filas de campos relacionados con el usuario, siendo que estos mismo contienen el mismo id del los inputs?

El problema es que no me valida bien ningun campo de las dos filas, antes si lo hacia cuanod solo era una fila, pero ahora que el formulario me regresar mas filas de resultados no me valida ninguno ni otro, leeí en internet que los id son unicos y no se si eso sea el problema.

Comment: edite el codigo ya que las condiciones van dentro de una funcion que ejecuta al evento onsubmit

Comment: como lo tenias antes o ahora no ha cambiado mucho. aparte creo que eso no ayudaba en tu solución al problema principal. Como comentaste no puedes tener id repetido, ya que al momento de ir a buscar ese id javascript no va a saber cual es el que se requiere, podrías partir solucionando eso.

Comment: si tiene razon, solo que no se como hacer que ese id ya no se repita

Comment: ese id se genera dinámico o lo asignas tu ? por que si es dinámico puedes añadirle el valor de un contador para que te quede como  id1, id2, ....

Comment: lo asigno yo. Ya intente agregarle un contador a cada id del elemento pero ni así me funciono, con eso solo me pudo validar la primer fila y la otra la ignoro

Comment: tienes donde se pueda revisar tu código? como para verlo funcionar. de igual manera si tu asignas los id, no es necesario el contador, ponle algo que los diferencie como myidprimero, myidsegundo, como te sea mas conveniente a ti.

Comment: mire acabo de edita la publicacion agregue el codigo completo con el formulario y sus validaciones js, todo se hace en el mismo archivo y pues agregue una descripcion de lo que hice para los contadores, solo que  esto me valida solo parte de la primer fila y la otra fila la ignora ocacinando que se envien los datos sin validad los campos.

Comment: Por lo que entendí de tu código que lo mire un buen rato, es que las dos filas siguen teniendo los mismos id, por que no vi un incremento de la variable $f, al final estas incrementado $i que la usas en el name pero no en el id

Comment: es que la variable $i la uso para otra cosa con php y no para lo que quiero hacen con java script por lo que trato de incrementar $f

Comment: Sin código es un juego de adivinanzas, no se te puede ayudar si no publicas el código.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba si funciona hacer el código con ELSEIF no con puro IF ya que si no valida el primero siempre va a ir de 1 en 1 por mas que el resultado sea true o false

Comment: le agregue los else if, solo que sigue sin validarme los campos de las filas

Comment: proba fNe3 == null solo con eso en los if o solo con el fNe3 == 0 xq basicamente es lo mismo o si no con && y no con ||